# Left Join takes very long time on 150 000 rows

Tags: mysql

I am having some difficulties to accomplish a task.

Here is some data from `orders` table:

```
+----+---------+
| id | bill_id |
+----+---------+
|  3 |       1 |
|  9 |       3 |
| 10 |       4 |
| 15 |       6 |
+----+---------+
```

And here is some data from a `bills` table:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

**I want to list all the `bills` that have no `order` associated with.**

In order to achieve that, I thought that the use of `LEFT JOIN` was appropriated so I wrote this request:

```
SELECT * FROM bills
  LEFT JOIN orders
    ON bills.id = orders.bill_id
WHERE orders.bill_id IS NULL;
```

I thought that I would have the following result:

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| bills.id | orders.id | orders.bill_id |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
|        2 | NULL      | NULL           |
|        5 | NULL      | NULL           |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

But I can't reach the end of the request, it has run more than 5 minutes without result, I stopped the request because this can't be a production time anyway.

**My real dataset has more than 150 000 `orders` and 100 000 `bills`. Is the dataset too big?**

**Is my request wrong somewhere?**

Thank you very much for your tips!

**EDIT:** side note, the tables have no foreign keys defined... *flies away*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine.  I would use table aliases in writing it:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bills b LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON b.id = o.bill_id
WHERE o.bill_id IS NULL;
```

You don't need the `NULL` columns from `orders`, probably.

You need an index on `orders(bill_id)`:

```
create index idx_orders_billid on orders(bill_id);
```

Comment: I assume this would be the solution... Problem is, `orders` table is actually filled with `bill_id` = 0, and I just realized the database is just completely unhealthy... Thanks for your response, but I went with a hacky php script at the end...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Just looking to learn... what is the purpose of using table aliases here?  Does that help for optimization?

Comment: @watermelon . . . I always use table aliases when a query has more than one table.  And only omit them when there is one table because I can be lazy.

Answer (score 0):

By your where statement, I assume your looking for orders that have no bills.

If that's the case you don't need to do a join to the bills table as they would by definition not exist.

You will find

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE orders.bill_id IS NULL;
```

A much better performing query.

Edit:

Sorry I missed your "I want to list all the bills that have no order associated with." when reading the question. As @gordon pointed out an index would certainly help. However if changing the scheme is feasible I would rather have a nullable bill.order_id column instead of a order.bill_id because you won't need a left join, an inner join would suffice to get order bills as it would be a quicker query for your other assumed requirements.